# How do you combine -r and -c for gunzip?

Tags: recursive, gzip

I am trying to recursively `gunzip` files (`-r`) but don't have permission in their original location to store them.  I know to change the location for a single file you do `gunzip {file} -c > {new file location}`, but I don't see how you combine the two such that you say keep the original directory structure of the original file locations and have that same directory structure in the new location.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix with GNU find (including Linux) you can use that for the recursion AND iteration

```
 find . -name '*.gz' -exec sh -c 'gunzip -c "{}" >"/output/path/{}"' \;
```

On other Unix/find embedded {} may not work so I think you need shell (assuming Bourneish)

```
 find . -name '*.gz' | while read f; do gunzip -c "$f" >"/output/path/$f"; done
```

This assumes no subdirectory is named something.gz, which would be perverse; if so add `-type f`. If *all* files are gzipped, `-type f` alone is enough.

But it might be **easier** to **copy** the tree of compressed files to the writable location **first** (lots of ways on Unix: `cp -R`, `rsync -r`, `tar cf - | (cd somewhere; tar xf -)` and even on Windows `xcopy`) and uncompress the copies.

Comment: The first one works for me as long as the topmost directory exists in the output path (say a gz file was found in ./special, then /output/path/special had better exist).  I had though about cp first, but the collective size of the files to be gunzipped makes this not so good a solution.  Could work for a smaller set of files.